# AngularJS Path Change Event

Tags: angularjs

`appContoller.js`

```
if (location.path() == '/login')
{
//logic
}
else if(location.path() == '/view'){
//logic
}
else
{
//logic
}
```

I'm using the location.path() to find the current page in the controller page, but this is working only with refresh not with the redirect or clicking the href in the page.
location.path() executed once, when the appController is instantiated, at the very beginning of the application. So it gets the location at that moment, and stores it in a variable. The variable never changes after.

So i want to track the path in JS, how i can use path change events in the conroller js so that the above code will work without the refresh

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have some bad design in your application.

You should have your config like below

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        // route for default home page
        .when('/view', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/view.html',
            controller  : 'viewController'
        })
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/login.html',
            controller  : 'loginController'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo:'/login'});
});
```

There should be two different controllers for '/login' and for '/view' paths.